# Hadoop Examples Sort Validation

Tags: validation, sorting, hadoop

In hadoop-examples.jar,
I know for TeraSort we can use TeraValidate for validating the output.
Is there a similar way to validate the output of Sort example ?

Also, I tried with TeraValidate to validate the Sort output but it gives me an error.

Following is the output of TeraValidate,

```
> error misorder in part-00001 last: ';:widdl' current: ')(winga'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'scrat bact' current: 'FEBassa'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'FEBassa' current: '?>Fouqu'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: '?>Fouqu' current: '=<Itali'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'shola spec' current: 'XWLemur'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'biventer L' current: '43Mesua'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'ploration ' current: 'pinulus ar'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'pinulus ar' current: 'hgShiah'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'pendulant ' current: '/.Tamil'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: '`_Whilk' current: '54Yanni'
> error misorder in part-00001 last: 'ribaldrous' current: 'cinque cha'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked teravalidate only works for terasort. There is no standard job to verify the output of Sort.

Thats the reason TeraSort is used for most of the benchmarking jobs, because it has all there TeraGen,TeraSort,TeraValidate for itself.